# Python:Regex to remove more than N consecutive letters

Tags: python, regex

lets say I have this string : Sayy Hellooooooo

if N = 2

I want the result to be (Using Regex): Sayy Helloo

Thank U in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could build the regex dynamically for a given `n`, and then call `sub` without callback:

```
import re

n = 2
regex = re.compile(rf"((.)\2{{{n-1}}})\2+")

s = "Sayy Hellooooooo"
print(regex.sub(r"\1", s))  # Sayy Helloo
```

#### Explanation:

- `{{`: this double brace represents a literal brace in an f-string
- `{n-1}` injects the value of `n-1`, so together with the additional (double) brace-wrap, this `{{{n-1}}}` produces `{2}` when `n` is 3.
- The outer capture group captures the maximum allowed repetition of a character
- The additional `\2+` captures **more** subsequent occurrences of that same character, so these are the characters that need removal.
- The replacement with `\1` thus reproduces the *allowed* repetition, but omits the *additional* repetition of that same character.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `re.sub` with a callback:

```
N = 2

result = re.sub(r'(.)\1+', lambda m: m.group(0)[:N], your_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use backreferences to mach the previous character. So `(a|b)\1` would match `aa` or `bb`. In your case you would want probably any letter and any number of repetitions so `([a-zA-Z])\1{n,}` for N repetitions. Then substitute it with one occurence using `\1` again. So putting it all together:

```py
import re

n=2

expression = r"([a-zA-Z])\1{"+str(n)+",}"
print(re.sub(expression,r"\1","hellooooo friiiiiend"))
# Outputs Hello friend
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY32zJzC_KLShSKUrm48myNuLhSKwqKUouLM_PzFGwVipQ0ohN1qxx1o2I1YwyrlbSLS4o08jS1lXRqlbgKijLzSjSKUvWKS5M0ENp0ipRiDJV0lDJSc3LyQUAhrSgTBFLzUpQ0NbmUFfxLSwpKS4oVPFJzwJJACYhroI6COQ4AA)

Note this actually matches N+1 repetitions only, like your test cases. One item then N copies of it. If you want to match exactly N also subtract 1.

Remember to use `r` in front of regular expressions so you don't need to double escape backslashes.

Learn more about backreferences: https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html Learn more about repetition: https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: If you want to generalize for all `N` you should replace with `r"\1"*n`

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex that search for multiple occurence of the same char, that is done with `(.)\1` (the `\1` matches the group 1 (in the parenthesis))

To match

- 2 occurences : `(.)\1`
- 3 occurences : `(.)\1\1` or `(.)\1{2}`
- 4 occurences : `(.)\1\1\1` or `(.)\1{3}`

So you can build it with an f-string and the value you want (that's a bit ugly because you have literal brackets that needs to be escaped using double brackets, and inside that the bracket to allow the value itself)

```
def remove_letters(value: str, count: int):
    return re.sub(rf"(.)\1{{{count}}}", "", value)


print(remove_letters("Sayy Hellooooooo", 1))  # Sa Heo
print(remove_letters("Sayy Hellooooooo", 2))  # Sayy Hello
print(remove_letters("Sayy Hellooooooo", 3))  # Sayy Hellooo
```

---

You may understand the pattern creation easier with that

```
r"(.)\1{" + str(count) + "}"
```

Comment: The middle case should output "Sayy Helloo" according to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

- When `N=2`: the **regex** pattern is compiled to : `((\w)\2{2,})`
- When `N=3`: the **regex** pattern is compiled to : `((\w)\2{3,})`

#### Code:

```
import re
N = 2
p = re.compile(r"((\w)\2{" + str(N) + r",})")

text = "Sayy Hellooooooo"
matches = p.findall(text)

for match in matches:
    text = re.sub(match[0], match[1]*N, text)

print(text)
```

#### Output:

```
Sayy Helloo
```

#### Note:

Also tested with `N=3`, `N=4` and other text inputs.